# Laravel Excel Export with Vlookup formula multiple sheets

Tags: php, excel-formula, laravel-8, phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

I have a working environment with many exports using Laravel-Excel (maatwebsite.nl).

In an export I would like to achieve the following.
I have multiple sheets and would like to have a sheet where i would use a Vlookup formula that searches values from another sheet. the expected result would be the following:

in Column A user will type(scan) an SKU and in Colunm B the Vlookup formula would search the given sku from another sheet for the product name.

But in my export I have #N/A in all cells that contains the forumula, not even have the formula in the field only #N/A.
In my config file the  'pre_calculate_formulas' => false is set.

Is there any idea?

thank you!

Comment: some sample data / a visual to relieve the headache of trying to construct a picture this side - maybe a screenshot or two - that would be amazing pls ta

Comment: Sorry for causing headache, I understand that you wanted to help and it was really hard without some picture or sample code. sorry again.

Comment: Hi @Tomekhun - not prob buddy-  can't you j just show the two lists in the same sheet and we can pretend they are in two diferent sheet) - then 4 or so rows is fine - I get you have "sku"in one heading in one sheet - just don't get what else you're talking about and I'll have to submit to missing plot altogether if your solution is what you were actually looking for!! missed the boat I did (as yoga or someone would say lol)...

Answer (score 0):

I came to a realization than in cases where export extension is set to XLS not XLSX some formulas are only can be exported as TEXT.

such formula is VLOOKUP.

so if you use XLSX as the export extension than the VLOOKUP is present as a formula [vlookup is present in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reUld.png)

```
     Excel::download((new exportClass(), 'filename.XLSX');
```